# Space exploration jobs

Tags: discussion

This admittedly is a self-serving question.

I know that StackOverflow has a way to advertise for jobs; my employer has used it. The problem is that we're not getting good matches. Is there a way to advertise for jobs on Space.SE?

Comment: The company makes a lot of extras only on the SO. I think, they seem to handle SE with very low prio. Having a clear user voice might affect their this behavior in a positive direction.

Comment: If only... Would save me so many LinkedIn &c filters that barely work...

Comment: I think this community is rich with potential candidates; it seems this would be a great idea and beneficial to all parties. "Hey; there are *job listings* at Space SE, check it out!"

Comment: Going out on a limb here maybe, but would we as a community be able to allow job postings on SE meta, or does that violate some rules? We could think of a special tag and requiring some minimum level of rep so that only people that have some binding with the community can post.

Comment: @Ludo I doubt that the powers that be would allow that. If organizations were allowed to directly post a job opening here on meta, it would (a) be indistinguishable from spam, (b) represent a loss of income to the SE owners, and (c) not achieve the desired goal for the organization. Organizations want lots of eyes, and lots of the right kinds of eyes, to see their job postings. While space.SE gets a lot fewer eyes than does SO, they are the right kinds of eyes. Meta.space.SE gets a lot fewer eyes than does space.SE.

Comment: If any, [SO is sunsetting Jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293/2821954).

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure there is. Presumably if your company already has contacts with Stack Overflow, they can request that they target this site as well. See the link below about advertising.

Comment: I only see ads for jobs when I go to StackOverflow. (I'm a member there as well as here.) I have yet to see a job posting on any of the StackExchange sites on which I am a member.

Comment: Talk to the ad manager is all I can really offer. It seems like ads on non-SO sites are rare, but if a request is made, it is more likely to be able to happen.

Comment: I imagine SO and SE run off the same code-base, so inserting ads should not be difficult.

Comment: @Ludo Inserting ads is not difficult, but inserting the Job SO functionality and then maintaining it, yes it is. And they are not cheap even for things not needing developer work. I think, yes that money exists for what they would do it, but it is surely not a small sum.